# Flash 10.1 Multitouch in OSX

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, macos, multi-touch

Hey, I want to play with the new multitouch functionality of Flash 10.1 as is demonstrated here: http://blog.martinlegris.com/2009/12/13/tutorial-multi-touch-in-as3-flash-player-101-part-1/#more-186

```
removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
// entry point
_tf = new TextField();
_tf.width = stage.stageWidth;
_tf.height = stage.stageHeight;
_tf.mouseEnabled = false;
addChild(_tf);
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
_tf.text = "Input Mode: " + Multitouch.inputMode + "\n";
_tf.appendText("Touch Points: " + Multitouch.maxTouchPoints + "\n");
_tf.appendText("Supports Touch Events: " + Multitouch.supportsTouchEvents + "\n");
```

But when I do it with my new MacBookPro running osx 10.6.1, I get:

```
InputMode: none;
Touch Points: 0;
Supports Touch Events: false;
```

Now, I know that it is supported on the MacBooks, because this guy posted a video of it: http://theflashblog.com/?p=1666

Is there something I need to do different to make that first bit of code to work properly on OSX? A driver to install or something? Can anyone who has got this up and running let me know what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Currently on Mac, Multitouch only works inside the AIR runtime, and in addition, the low level touch events are not available. GestureEvents are available, so now my problem is more complicated: I can do Multitouch.supportsGestureEvents which returns true... and I can list out which gesture events I can listen to, ROTATE, PAN, etc. but nothing happens. I can't get any of the events to trigger.

Comment: I tried setting this up too and it doesn't work.  I am using a Macbook from 2007/2008 I think (got it used).  I read that only Macbooks made after late 2008, even with the latest OS (which, after 10.5.8, all support multitouch gestures), won't support multitouch.  You either need to buy a newer macbook or get a touchpad I think.  I'd like to know if you or anyone get this to work on older macbooks :).

Comment: i have the latest generation multitouch macbook pro with snow leopard

Answer (score 0):

only gestures work on the mac.  Check out this post http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/multitouch_gestures.html